# How to resize a Responsive image and maintain height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.home-slider img {
  margin-right: 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 35px;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}

.home-slider-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.home-slider-wrap .bg-img {
  height: 500px;  
  width: auto;
  max-width: none;
}

.img-full {
  width: 100%;
}


@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .home-slider-wrap .bg-img { 
    min-height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
    <div class="home-slider-wrap">
      <div class="home-slider">
        <div>
          <img src="https://g5-assets-cld-res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/q_auto,f_auto,fl_lossy/g5/g5-c-1t2d31r8-berkshire-communities/g5-cl-i2pbvvuq-creekstone/uploads/pet-friendly.jpg" class="bg-img img-full ing-responsive" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to resize this image but at the same time also keep a minimum height for devices less than 768px; However as you can see in the demo below, this ain't working out.

The portion of the cat and dog isn't visible when the page is resized for a mobile device.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/iwant2learn/pen/godQOz)

How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably want just the opposite: ... _also keep a minimum height for devices more than 767px_ ... & _The portion of the cat and dog isn't visible when the page is **NOT** resized for a mobile device._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp)

Comment: Can you show me how? I have updated the demo using media query and it is making no difference

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this css:

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Where will I add this? Can you show it in the demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query to target below 768px width devices to define style like below -

```
@media (max-width:767px){
    .home-slider-wrap .bg-img {
        min-height: auto;
        min-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
  }
```

Comment: @media (max-width: 767px){
.home-slider-wrap .bg-img {
    min-height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}}

Comment: u can set min-height to image for below 767px. but setting auto height is advisable.